# Rewriting URL without the user seeing it

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp

I try to add a rule to my htaccess to make it possible for me to route all article urls to be loaded by the same file.

> Input: localhost/Project/article/my-test-article
>
> Output: localhost/Project/article.php?id=my-test-article

I'm currently using this code... Which works:

```
#Enable backend url rewriting
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Project/

#Route articles
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^artikkel/(.*)$ article.php?id=$1 [R]
```

Problem is, I don't want the user to be able to SEE the `?id=my-test-article`!
I don't want the url to change at all, really.
I just need it to always load the same file all the time!

What would I have to do to accomplish that?
I'm using WAMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want the url to change in browser, Remove the **R** flag.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Project/

#Route articles
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^artikkel/(.*)$ article.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, and it KIND OF works... Problem then, is that my css files won't load from the same base.

I use the same css file for the index.php and the article.php.
For the index it can be loaded normally using "js/main.js" but for the articles I must use "../js/main.js" which is not very convinient. How to fix that?

Comment: @Ledii to fix the css js and relative links , Add a base tage to the head of your document **<base href="/">**

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Just had to refactor some code.